# Householder matrix Uw acts as the identity on the subspace w

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

How can i show that a Householder matrix $U_w$ acts as the identity on the subspace $w$?
and that it acts as a reflection on the one-dimensional subspace spanned by
w; i.e.,  $U_w(x) = x$ if $x$ is perpendicular to $w$ and $U_w(w) = -w$.

Comment: Is this is a homework problem?

Comment: Do you know how the Householder matrix is defined?

Comment: Yes this is. This is from the book Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson. The Uw is defined as 

Uw = I − 2ww∗

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|w\|_2=1$, then with $U=I-2ww^*$, $Uw=(I-2ww^*)w=w-2ww^*w=w-2w=-w$. If $w^*x=0$, $Ux=x-2ww^*x=x-0=x$.

Comment: Thank You. It helped alot. The other property can be proved just like that taking into care the fact that if x is perpendicular to w, then w*x will be 0. which will give a result of -w.